# Reusing Action error - There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'projectName'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewdata

I realize this is a frequently asked question but none of the answered I located seemed to fix my issue.

I have an action in my controller that populates a drop down using info from a database.

Everything works fine until I try to reuse the drop down in another view.

Controller

```
public ActionResult ImportAddresses1([Bind(Include = "ProjectID, ProjectName")] ProjectMaster projectName)
{
   ViewBag.ProjectName = new SelectList(db.ProjectMaster, "ProjectID", "ProjectName");    
   return View();
}
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProjectName", null, "-- Please select a project --", htmlAttributes: new { id = "projectselect", title = "ProjectName", @class = "form-control", })
```

Again it works fine in one view but not when I try to use itin another view.

What am I missing?

The goal is to just reuse this drop down in another view.

[Drop down needed to repeat in several views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRZI8.png)

Comment: can you show controller action and its view code where it is not working, the above code is not enough to find the problem

Comment: My original thinking was I could simply reuse the same code:

    @Html.DropDownList("ProjectName", null, "-- Please select a project --", htmlAttributes: new { id = "projectselect", title = "ProjectName", @class = "form-control", })

in my new view as I simply need to have the same drop down in another view making the same call to the above controller action.

eg.

View 1 (this one works)
          Action called "ImportAddresses1"
View 2(this one does not)

Comment: in the controller action of that view, you need to write the code for setting the `ViewBag.ProjectName` will also be needed

Comment: If you are saying I need code to set the ViewBag for the second view I have tried that without success. 

ie.

    ViewBag.ProjectName1 = new SelectList(db.ProjectMaster, "ProjectID", "ProjectName");

   return View();

From your last comment It seems you are saying I need a separate action for the second view.  I tried that and same results

Comment: Why did you call it `ViewBag.ProjectName1` in your second action when in your view the property that you are referencing is called `ProjectName`? Make sure that you have a `ViewBag.ProjectName = ...` line in your second action, the same way you have it in the first controller action.

Comment: My original thinking is I could use DRY (don't repeat yourself) and have 2 views using the same action (in this case "ImportAddresses1" which just populates a drop down. The same drop down and info is needed in other views. What is needed to achieve this?

I tried calling "ImportAddresses1" from the second view using the same code from view one.

I have also tried setting up a second action with a different name form the second view using the same code as the action  "ImportAddresses1" and the same code for the drop down for the second view that I used in view one.

Comment: It means that the value of `projectName` is `null`. You need to populate it in your controller method before you pass it to the view.

Comment: @Stephen

I don't get what you are saying.

   public ActionResult ImportAddresses1([Bind(Include = "ProjectID, ProjectName")] ProjectMaster projectName)
{
   ViewBag.ProjectName = new SelectList(db.ProjectMaster, "ProjectID", "ProjectName");    
   return View();
}


populates fine when called from the 1st view.

The issue is when I use the same action from a different view it is not.

Comment: I repeat, the error means that the value of `ProjectName` is `null`. I don't even know if the code you have shown is for the first view that works or the 2nd view that does not (and the error message states `projectName` (lowercase `p`) but you code has uppercase `ProjectName`. And the signature of your method makes no sense - why do you have a complex object as a parameter in a GET method, and it contains properties which are the same names as the object your using to generate the `SelectList`, and the name of the parameter is also `projectName` (lower case)

Comment: This thread seems to headed down a rabbit hole so I'm going to try to explain my issue again.  The initial code in the question is working code. My problem arises when I try to use the same action from another view. I understand that what is happening is that when I attempt from my second view I am getting null values hence the error. What I am seeking guidance on is how do I fix the issue. Code examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue. I had experiences numerous PC lockups during earlier development on the project. I decided to redo the project from scratch and then re purposed my forms and controllers by pasting my code into news ones I created (allowing new scaffolding to occur ) and all is well.

Thank you to everyone who responded.